# Nginx redirect https://ip to https://domain

Tags: nginx

I have a script that is out of my control, that creates links that redirect to my server IP but with `https://` on it.

This obviously create issues with the certificate. I can redirect my `ip` to `http://domain` fine but I can't make `ip` > `https://domain` work?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.0.1;

    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name 192.168.0.1;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;


    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

After that block I have another `server {}` listening on port `80` and `443` but with `server_name` using my domain if that matters.

I redacted my IP's obviously I'm using real IP's in my configuration file

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Your question doesn't say what the problem is.

Comment: My certificate is not valid for https://myip so it causes issues. But now that I'm thinking, it's not possible to do a redirect before validating the cert right? So this issue is not possible to fix on nginx, since any redirection would happen after certificate validation, and I don't have certs for my bare ip

Comment: So, create a cert for your ip.

Comment: not possible with letsencrypt :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get a TLS certificate for an IP address that browsers will recognize. You will have to fix the script which generates the inappropriate redirects. That actually is possible.